# Initial Contour in Level-Set-Method

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am learning Level-Set-Method for the image segmentation.

I have a simple question, how people draw the initial contour in the given image, when people need to deform it?

Is there a command in MATLAB, or we need create it?

If we need to create it, is there an example?

Comment: Just write a bit of MATLAB code to create the initial signed distance function.

Comment: I think maybe the MATLAB bwdist function is helpful for creating the initial signed distance function. Also, when you use the level set method, I think you are supposed to occasionally redistance $\phi$ to make it a signed distance function again. You might be able to use your redistancing code to help create the initial signed distance function.